# How to un-blacklist Graphics Driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04

I am trying to get nvidia driver working on my computer. After changing directory to /var/log and running `cat gpu-manager.log` , this is the result:

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/updates/dkms
Found nvidia module: nvidia-modeset.ko
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? yes
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? yes
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:5917
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:1d10
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? no
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
output 0:
    card0-eDP-1
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 1
Does it require offloading? yes
last cards number = 2
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 2
Has the system changed? No
Intel IGP detected
Intel hybrid system
Nvidia driver version 396.54 detected
Creating /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-prime.conf'
```

According to the results, nvidia driver is loaded, but blacklisted. Does nayone know how to fix that?

Edit: After taking a look in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, I found that it was filled with incomprehensible gimberish:

```
¡ÃÈÂ± vë1d¡)^ZSv<95>n²è³¹<8f>èéuößí`^S ^H<8d>¸Pç^UækÀ<8f>^HB<98>^ZßT<97>$â¯^Ç<94>^OJ<80>vZÞLø,qÄ¨²tEZÿ!¬àÁë<87>W<9a>^]ÑÊ^Nz]d<89>ûqºâkY<8c>5/^W°/<91>¼^E8^]/ð^Cb<97>µ<9a>}|A'^Mù ´¹¼ç¶"\²úF»^RIfá¾!¤'V^O<80>dá<98>u¹;*³1*<9c><~N^HÂ<94>^Qw<99>Q×«B^N^F£<80><83>ÒË<8d>²¦<8b>:<9b>¬7t°0×=7Î¸u^^=^US0¯Ïf<9a><83>^V?^GË÷&<89>7Ôéd^Mâ<95>»'jÈkW^R<ä ÚôÖ^VÏPæ7£Ix;ô}lH<8f>ÜRÙj²åà;b"1g×'Iì+äNÌ3^O[+@ã<95>FHJÊ^Q^\Ï^G5½®$ÒG)8`w+^K^KÔÅq»^Vc½ôoÎºýbMà<99>^R<84>Ù^]^Rë^\(´ùJ<81>²^ZØJ<9e>a<9d> ­+HÍ<9b>´´ÁO<8f>(ðy¼(^P\nb2Ú<88>È¯Êò*Ù¢»KL4MÞàÝf8^_<92>^HÙ«ÙºÜ^L^Q^K¥D8¨<97>      ã<8b>>^UC^X<91>t^]kC=ë<93>U$Þß\¿BRgB<95>Ñ5<97>ãÂ¡¥0à^OÆ<9e>ÿ<9b>:>hÅ²ü<81>^N<96>b
#)ÿô`É<8e>+W2Ì^WTÃ|<99>û<8f><8e><9b><9f>z/òkË§<8d>2¹M^L Oëu7<92>^?^?°<88>â6×l]ó®<99>4Ì¸DÃkv+ÄøLÄENL<83>WªºÞy^?^^<8a>^^ñ<9c><8e>¹Ú-°Í­¬$^G¨wvã·<85>^E:<93>^S
Û<85>,^Z3Á^]mBP^H^F^EÜ<95>^TÉ^W¥Pþò
PÃñÛ^\¯¼B<88>Ý^[Q^î9<95>`«¶ÁEHk÷8²@^]á<82>A^Pvß^L<9b>Ñäò<98>^C§<80>^K<92>4q<85>EåVSÄµ«^[[b^KÅâ<93>ãÝi§Á©ë#^OXÂ§<8a><93>³<89>bi<88>3D[ìãY<80><9b>?^NC;J´¯ÞæçÀØ^]J7T*s8ûÐ^OùO¥l{,ü.8L{ÃÑi^N÷Á<99>^^Ò%<9b>¶8qß&^U<8c>4¥dà`<9c>^V°Ïï<9e>d-^P,<98>¢#Å<99>a×äÕ-^Qz <9c>£§qvºýe½ô<80>,þ<89>Âá<8f>FI_gÉ<80>í=²PÈù»l'4<91>2^]<8a>^^L     Õ®^?^\8Â|Ö¨;ù~<8a>=<86>ÒÊDÂõú^_ÏsÁ%ñ^L!j«^O<93>ºðu<89><82>xæÜß¦ÆZ<95>îMYäS<9b>O<9c>Z©GKÐ<dÜ'ñ±¼"<98>Oó^V½>}]<82><85>¶J-­<8a>,ÕÂ<89>Ýõ<80>'¹àô¾(²^Hí<97>é$<94>^@NGD><94>Nx<84>÷  Wü/
```

What on Earth does that mean ?!?!

Answer (score 1):

If you're running 18.04.1, then replace your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` with this...

```
# This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd

# replaced by e100
blacklist eepro100

# replaced by tulip
blacklist de4x5

# causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth1394

# snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
# hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810)
blacklist snd_intel8x0m

# Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device)
blacklist snd_aw2

# causes failure to suspend on HP compaq nc6000 (Ubuntu: #10306)
blacklist i2c_i801

# replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54

# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx

# most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565)
blacklist garmin_gps

# replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721)
blacklist asus_acpi

# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
blacklist snd_pcsp

# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr

# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac
```

Answer (score 0):

The blacklist file should only contain text data, and that data looks like binary data. Either a.) At some point you accidentally copied a binary file over your blacklist text file or b.) Your disk is corrupting data.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer, but rather it should be a comment to the original question. Please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf** file if it is present.