# Nvidia GPU not detected in system

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu

I'm trying to install drivers for the Nvidia GPU built into my laptop. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and the gpu is a Geforce GTX 950M. Nothing I do can get the GPU to show up as even installed in the laptop.

`ubuntu-drivers devices` displays nothing, `lscpi` has no mention of Nvidia or an installed card. `glxinfo` also doesn't show anything about Nvidia, it says my OpenGL vendor is Intel. When I try to install the drivers manually from the runfile I downloaded from Nvidia, it says that no compatible GPU was detected.

In my BIOS, I have secure boot disabled, and there's no setting for me to enable/disable a dedicated GPU (so I assume that it's enabled by default). Despite all this, I'm unable to find my GPU. Installing the drivers from aptitude doesn't change any of this behavior, and the Nvidia Settings application doesn't show a GPU installed either.

Any help is appreciated, I'm very confused.

Edit: My full config is:

- Acer Aspire V5-591G-56AS

  - Intel i5-6300HQ @ 2.3 Ghz
  - 16 GB DDR3 RAM
  - NVidia GTX 950M
  - 128 GB M.2 SSD
  - 1TB HDD
- Ubuntu 18.04

  - Kernel 4.15.0-46-generic
  - i3 Window Manager

Edit 2: Something I just remembered that might be relevant. About a year ago, I accidentally sent 9 volts through a USB port, which shorted something in the port (confirmed with a multimeter). Ever since, the USB port is constantly 'active' and drains my battery regardless of sleep state, so I keep my laptop plugged in all the time. I can't think of any other reason why my GPU wouldn't be showing up, but I also don't think the USB port/controller and the GPU are directly connected, so I'm not sure why it would have any effect.

Edit 3: Contents of [/var/log/gpu-manager.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VKyrbgznZW/)

Comment: what laptop (and config) are you running?

Comment: I've added as much information as I thought relevant, let me know if I missed something @YouriKoeman

Comment: Is it detected on Windows? If it is, your GPU probably still works so you can exclude that.

Comment: I don't have Windows installed, currently in the process of reinstalling to answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

I try to install from nvidia site , but it is unsuccessful.

Please try

https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Nvidia Driver Version 418

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, nothing changes.

Comment: Please remove nvidia from blacklist .

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079844/how-to-un-blacklist-graphics-driver

Comment: My gpu-manager.log and gpu-manager-switch.log both show that a) Nvidia is not being loaded b) Nvidia is not blacklisted. I added a link to the output of my gpu-manager.log in the original post. Plus, my `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file already matches the one in the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing problem where Ubuntu (20.04.1) was not able to detect my NVIDIA graphics (RTX2060).

I checked the command `nvidia-smi` and it showed that it cannot communicate with the NVIDIA drivers.

I solved it using following commands (Nvidia driver already should be installed `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455` or from software & update - Additional driver section )

```
prime-select query
sudo prime-select intel
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Then I installed CUDA using `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`. Finally reboot.